# changing vertical bars color in a graph using Dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

I am designing a graph using Dygraph range selection option.The graph is represented using Vertical bars instead of line series. I have cases where there are more than two y-values for single x-value. Is it possible to give different colors for different bars when they overlap, so that identifying each bar becomes easy and usable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sunil

Comment: Have you looked at this example from their site: http://dygraphs.com/tests/plotters.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in an array of colors in the chart options:

```
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("g_div"),
                 "X,Bar1,Bar2,Bar3\n" +
                 "1,10,11,12\n" +
                 "2,7,17,5\n" +
                 "3,6,23,12\n" +
                 "4,4,27,10\n" +
                 "5,3,30,23\n" +
                 "6,2,32,5\n" +
                 "7,1,33,17\n",
                   {
                     // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
                     legend: 'always',
                     animatedZooms: true,
                     plotter: multiColumnBarPlotter,
                     colors: ["#00A0B0", "#6A4A3C", "#CC333F", ],
                     dateWindow: [0, 8]
                 });
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4X227/)**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is for different series but if for the same series there is overlap of two values , then is there a way we can represent two bars with different color or two bars with different thickness.